# How to pipe text output to speech dispatcher?

Tags: bash, pipe, spd-say

I am not getting the command pipe to work for `say` and `spd-say`. Specifically, I want to pipe the output of `fortune` to `spd-say`, which seems more advanced than `say`. I tried the usual pipe construction

```
fortune | spd-say
```

Other commands do work, like

```
fortune | wc
```

Apparently, the speech dispatcher commands treat the piped input different from the ordinary arguments. I would like to fix this and understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `-e` / `--pipe-mode` to read the text from stdin and process it. This also outputs the text to stdout.

```
$ fortune | spd-say -e
Don't feed the bats tonight.
```

Please read the info manual (`info spd-say`) which contains a few examples.

Comment: Quick side notes: if you have some kind of situation like: `echo $PRE_COLLECTED_INFO_MESSAGE ` make sure to put that variable in double quotes like:  `echo "$PRE_COLLECTED_INFO_MESSAGE"` especially if it potentially has newlines or punctuation in it. Otherwise some of the content may get "lost" before it makes it into spd-say. 
Also: if content is long, include the --wait parameter. Otherwise it might just quit in the middle of the sentence.